# How can I solve $\min \{ \langle A(x),y\rangle + f(y) \text{ s.t. } y \in S^n, \operatorname{tr}(y) =1, y \geq 0\}$?

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, nonlinear-optimization

I'm trying to solve the problem
$$\min \{ \langle A(x),y\rangle + f(y) \mid y \in S^m, \operatorname{tr}(y) =1, y \geq 0\}$$
where $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$, $y \in S^M$, that is, it's a symmetric $m$ by $m$ matrix. The operator $A(x)$ is given by $A(x) = \sum_{i=1}^n x_iA_i$ where $A_i$ is a $m$ by $m$ symmetric matrix for every $i$.

Of course, it will depend on the convex function $f(y)$, but let's say I have a way of viewing the operator $A(x)$ as a matrix $A \in \mathbb{R}^{m^2 \times n}$ and see the matrixes $y$ as a vector in $\mathbb{R}^{m^2}$ and also let's say that I have a method for calculating the minimum
$$\min \{ \langle Ax,z\rangle + f(z) \mid z \in R^p, \sum_{i=1}^p(z_i) = 1, z_i \geq 0\}$$
Is there a way I can make the problem above be a particular case of this and use the method for this problem instead?

On the problem above the function $f(y)$ is seen on a way that $y$ is already considered in $R^{m^2}$ so setting $z$ as the vector representation of $y$ and $p = m^2$ I get the same objective function, however how about the constraints?

Comment: Among other edits, I changed $\mathbb R^{m^2xn}$ to $\mathbb R^{m^2\times n}$. That is standard usage. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: Yes, if you "vectorize" your problem in this way you can apply any standard method. You have basically answered your own question, it seems to me.

Comment: But if I vectorize do I just need to solve the second problem then? How do the conditions on the trace suddenly become the conditions on the sum of the components?